# Почему в  Visual Studio не открывается последний проект?

Tags: visual-studio

Друзья, помогите. В Visual Studio, на стартовой странице, из списка последних проектов, а также по ссылке 'Open Project', не открывается последний незаконченный проект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может вы его перенесли в другое место? Попробуйте открыть его, указав место, не из последних, а указав место размещения.

Comment: Gorets, спасибо, получилось.